# Cut all Strings within Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to cut all the strings within an array. I have been trying to use array_walk but can't quite get it. Is there a simple PHP function to do this?

This array

```
{ 
[0]=> string(22) ""price":"292.67000000"" 
[1]=> string(22) ""price":"292.67000000"" 
[2]=> string(22) ""price":"292.75000000"" 
[3]=> string(22) ""price":"292.76000000""
}
```

becomes

```
{ 
[0]=> 292.67000000 
[1]=> 292.67000000 
[2]=> 292.75000000 
[3]=> 292.76000000
}
```

Code Currently:

```
<?php
$filename = file_get_contents('idfilebuy2015-03-12.txt');
$array = explode(",", $filename);
sort($array);

array_walk(chop($array);
array_walk(substr($array, 31);

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Sorry for the slow response. What is going on is I have a text data file that I am reading to an array in the PHP. 
Each line in the text file is going into a different value in the array. 
I want to cut the values in the array so that I only have a numbers to do calculations. Right now I have the whole string.

Comment: *I have been trying to use array_walk* Show us your attempt!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do here.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Are you going to edit this question?

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the slow response.

Comment: @JohnDown See my first comment ^ Show us your attempt to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through every array element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then I grab the float number out of every array element with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php))

```
<?php

    $arr = [
        '"price":"292.67000000"', 
        '"price":"292.67000000"',
        '"price":"292.75000000"',
        '"price":"292.76000000"',
    ];

    $arr = array_map(function($v){
        preg_match_all("/(\d+\.\d+)/", $v, $m);
        return $m[0][0];
    }, $arr);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 292.67000000 [1] => 292.67000000 [2] => 292.75000000 [3] => 292.76000000 )
```

Comment: Could you explain so I can learn? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnDown Did you saw my little explanation at the top of my answer? And if it is not enough I can expand, just let me know

Comment: I don't see an explanation just code?

Comment: @JohnDown Then please refresh the page. (I mean the: `Here I just...`)

Comment: @JohnDown You're welcome! (If I should expand just let me know)

Comment: @BheemRaj You're welcome! (If you look into the manual you see this: `Return array entries that match the pattern` So `preg_grep()` returns every entry which matches the pattern, not only the part of the pattern)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a number of other ways to do this.  What makes this tricky is the embedding of string characters (") in the strings, which makes many functions and built-in casting techniques not work.

Here's a way to do it that doesn't require the use of regex:

```
<?php
$prices = array('"price":"292.67000000"', '"price":"292.67000000"');

function f(&$item, $key) {
    $t = explode(':', $item);
    $item = trim($t[1], '"');
}

array_walk($prices, 'f');
print_r($prices);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 292.67000000
    [1] => 292.67000000
)
```